# How to exit else if loop in C

Tags: c, loops

I have been programming a C program for few days now, however I have met some problems that I am unable to solve.

My code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<windows.h>

int main()
{
   char user_type;
   printf("Welcome to XYZ Bank\n\n\n\n");
   printf("Hint: a for admin and c for customer\n");
   printf("Please input your account type (c/a):");
   scanf("%c",&user_type);
   system("cls");
   if (user_type=='c')
   {
       customer_login();
   }
   else if (user_type=='a')
   {
        admin_login();
   }
   else if (user_type!='c' || user_type!='a')
   {
       printf("Invalid selection is made, the program will restart");
       main();
   }
}
```

The problem that I faced is when the `user_type` is not `'a'` or `'c'`, the program is supposed to restart the `main()`, however all it does is to continue printing invalid selection.

Is there some command that allows me to restart `main()`? or is there a better way to do things? I think that a do while loop can be applied but I am not sure about it.

I am aware that the problem lies in the 3rd statement of my else-if loop, it would be helpful if somebody gave me tips on where to start.

Comment: `(user_type!='c' || user_type!='a')` will **always** be true. If `user_type=='c'`, then it's true that `user_type!='a'`. If `user_type=='a'`, then it's true that `user_type!='c'`. Thus, one or the other branch of that OR will hold.

Comment: @xing oh gosh that just solved everything! Thanks! so sorry for asking such a simple question

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yeah it was else before however I changed it, sorry for asking you to solve a flawed logic question, thanks!

Comment: Your program does not contain a loop -- though it should -- and in particular, `else if` does not constitute or create one.  It *does* call `main()` recursively, which is responsible for the repetition you see.  That's permitted, but it's rarely wise.

Comment: You could also  try making `main` call another function which does the work. You shouldn't be calling `main` yourself

Comment: @xing in this case do I use the while or do/while in the if?